# Can I receive desktop notification on Windows if an intranet server goes down?

Tags: windows, software-rec, network-monitoring

We are running an Ubuntu server on a Windows intranet. Is there an existing tool (possibly already part of Windows?) that could be configured to trigger a Windows desktop notification if the Ubuntu server goes down/becomes inaccessible?

I have tried [PingPlotter](https://alternativeto.net/software/pingplotter/) (freemium) and [GPING](https://alternativeto.net/software/gping-1/) (free software), but neither has a desktop notification option. I am not looking for a monitoring solution like [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org), just a "Server down" notification on my Windows desktop.

Comment: I believe this can be done with a powershell script. Just test the server periodically and raise a notification if test fails. Creating a windows notification in powershell : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730952.aspx , checking connectivity in powershell : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/02/24/use-powershell-to-test-connectivity-on-remote-servers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System Monitor for Growl for Windows](http://blog.growlforwindows.com/2011/06/system-monitor-updates.html) includes ping monitoring, http monitoring and server (port) monitoring. Notifications can be delivered as tooltips, message boxes or via [Growl for Windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx) (optional but recommended).

The trick was to stop searching for ping utilities (which mostly returned CLI and monitoring tools) and instead search for notification frameworks with plugins. [There are alternatives to Growl for Windows](https://alternativeto.net/software/growl-for-windows/), but I haven't checked which also include ping functionality.

Comment: Seems very useful.